# elementary OS 0.4 Loki Installation utility not working

Tags: system-installation

I've attempted to install elementary OS Loki at least ten times at this pont. Everything runs smoothly up until the end when I am told to restart the computer. If I restart and remove installation media, I am told that there is no OS installed, and if I don't I am returned to the install screen.

This happens with the BIOS in both uefi and legacy modes, with secure boot on or off.

EDIT: (I just remembered, The computer fails to recognize that an OS is present altogether although the installation program does. It also recognizes that the disk has been formatted and contains partitions made by the past attempts at install elementary OS.)

How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm having this same issue. I've tried to the installation about 4 times now. The installation guide doesn't say anything about the swap disk, boot loader, and other messages I keep getting when trying to start the installation.

Comment: Do you have more than one drive in your system? If so check the BIOS for the drive it's set to boot from first. If you only have one drive, well, disregard :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that this issue actually was not because of an issue with Grub, but rather an issue with the disk burner I used (Iso to USB) It, for whatever reason, fails to make proper disk images. YOU MUST USE RUFUS FOR ELEMENTARY OS TO PROPERLY INSTALL.

Answer (score 0):

While installing set the 'drive to install bootloader' as /dev/sdA

If that doesn't work, then try this method.

1. Create a bootable disk with Supergrub [link](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/category/download/supergrub2diskdownload/super-grub2-disk-stable/) using WinISO or PowerISO or any similar software in your USB stick.
2. Boot the Supergrub from USB. Supergrup auto-detects all the OS installed on your disks. Select the corresponding volume where elementary OS is installed.
3. Run the following commands in your elementary OS terminal

> sudo update-grub
>
> sudo grub-install /dev/sda

4. Reboot.